# How to select record count only for single value exclude record who are present for other value as well

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

On A student database, few students are enrolled in maths subjects, few in science, few in both subjects .

I want to select the rollno of students who have enrolled only in maths subject (not in science subject).

If I use following query then I will also get the rollnos who have enrolled in both (maths+science) but I want to exclude those roll nos.

select rollno from student where course='maths'

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: "If I use following query" - seems to be missing.

Comment: You are missing the query that you mention, also providing sample data and expected output would help us help you.

Comment: Read up where EXISTS and self joins

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT rollno
FROM Students
WHERE course in ('maths','science')
GROUP BY rollno
HAVING MAX(course) = 'maths';
```